# Unicode subscripts and superscripts in identifiers, why does Python consider XU == Xᵘ == Xᵤ?

Tags: python, unicode, syntax, identifier

Python allows unicode identifiers.  I defined `Xᵘ = 42`, expecting `XU` and `Xᵤ` to result in a `NameError`.  But in reality, when I define `Xᵘ`, Python (silently?) turns `Xᵘ` into `Xu`, which strikes me as somewhat of an unpythonic thing to do.  Why is this happening?

```
>>> Xᵘ = 42
>>> print((Xu, Xᵘ, Xᵤ))
(42, 42, 42)
```

Comment: PyCharm (2013.2.3) flags the `Xu, Xᵤ` as `unresolved references` but the code runs nonetheless

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: that'd be a bug in PyCharm, they are forgetting to normalise to the NFKC form.

Comment: How do I type these subscripts in Pycharm?  This is fantastic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Python converts all identifiers to their [NFKC normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization); from the [*Identifiers* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) of the reference documentation:

> All identifiers are converted into the normal form NFKC while parsing; comparison of identifiers is based on NFKC.

The NFKC form of both the super and subscript characters is the lowercase `u`:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', 'Xᵘ Xᵤ')
'Xu Xu'
```

So in the end, all you have is a single identifier, `Xu`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('Xᵘ = 42\nprint((Xu, Xᵘ, Xᵤ))', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (42)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (Xu)

  2           4 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (Xu)
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (Xu)
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (Xu)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 POP_TOP
             18 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

The above disassembly of the compiled bytecode shows that the identifiers have been normalised during compilation; this happens during parsing, any identifiers are normalised when creating the AST (Abstract Parse Tree) which the compiler uses to produce bytecode.

Identifiers are normalized to avoid many potential 'look-alike' bugs, where you'd otherwise could end up using both `ﬁnd()` (using the [*U+FB01 LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI*](https://codepoints.net/U+FB01) character followed by the ASCII `nd` characters) and `find()` and wonder why your code has a bug.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but should there not be a step in the `dis` where the name is converted to its NFKC form? In other words, should it not take a *tad* longer to define a value like that?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: no, because the identifier has been normalised *before* bytecode is produced, when parsing (a stage that converts tokens into an AST, which the compiler then uses to produce bytecode).

Comment: I see.  Yet normalisation does not prevent `a٨ = 42; a۸ = 43; a٨ == a۸` resulting in `False`…

Comment: @gerrit: 'many potential' is not *all* potential bugs. See the [codepoints.net page for *U+0668 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT EIGHT*](https://codepoints.net/U+0668) for more options to confuse that codepoint with.

Comment: @gerrit: there is a good reason that the Python style guide recommends all variable names to be ASCII-only English terms.

Answer (score 3):

Python, as of version 3.0, supports non-ASCII identifiers. When parsing the identifiers are converted using NFKC normalization and any identifiers where the normalized value is the same are considered the same identifier.

See PEP 3131 for more details. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/